Why doesn't MediaElement relativeOrAbsolute work in .NET8?
I'm trying to utilize MediaElement in WPF to play video files with .mp4 or .wmv extension. However, I'm having trouble passing the source as a relative path or Pack URI. The strange thing is that when I provide the absolute path it works fine. I'm curious if there are any changes to path resolution in .NET 8.0, since the same functionality works in .NET Framework 4.5.1.
 <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement"  LoadedBehavior="Manual"
  IsHitTestVisible="True" 
  Margin="10">
 </MediaElement>

Uri videoUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SampleProject;component/Videos/G.mp4",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
myMediaElement.Source = videoUri;

Is there any documentation?

Setting UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute for a WPF Pack URI makes no sense. Besides that, there seems to be a general problem with MediaElement, see here for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1649953/the-problem-with-the-mediaelement-in-wpf-net-8-0-n. I could not make it show a video at all, regardless whether I specify an absolute or relative path.

According to the Remarks in the online documentation, a Resource File Pack URIs would not work anyway. You would have to set the Build Action to Content and use a normal relative file URI.
